# Mostrar e esconder Div com Java Script

Tags: javascript

O código abaixo é para mostrar e esconder o conteúdo de uma `div`.

Estou tentando usar ele para mostra alguns vídeos, porém não consigo fazer ele mostrar mais que 2 vídeos.

Veja o código:

**Html**

```
<button id="opt1">Option 1</button>
<button id="opt2">Option 2</button>

 <div class="yesDisplay">
<p>Video 01</p>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6AmRg3p79pM?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>

 <div class="noDisplay">
<p>Video 02</p>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6AmRg3p79pM?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .noDisplay{display:none;}

 .yesDisplay{display:block;}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('#opt1').click(function(){
$('.yesDisplay').show();
$('.noDisplay').hide();
});

$('#opt2').click(function(){
$('.yesDisplay').hide();
$('.noDisplay').show();
});
```

Eu gostaria de mostrar até 8 vídeos nele e ao clicar em um botão a outra se esconda.  Se possível fazer isso com JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tens de programar o HTML e o JavaScript para serem escaláveis. Ou seja para funcionarem independentemente de quantos videos tens. Uma maneira de fazer isso seria assim:

```
var buttons = $('#videoGallery button');
var videos = $('#videoGallery div');

buttons.on('click', function () {
    var index = buttons.get().indexOf(this);
    videos.removeClass('yesDisplay');
    videos.eq(index).addClass('yesDisplay');
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qhe7gfd3/

Este código assume que tens todos os `button` e `div > iframe` dentro de um wrapper `#videoGallery` e que todas essas `div` estão escondidas. Ou sejam, não precisas da classe `noDisplay`. E depois só adicionas e removes classes. Nada de `.show()` e `.hide()`.

Comment: Poderia mostra esse exemplo com 6 videos ?  estou tentando adiciona mais videos e ao clica no botão aparece 2 videos ao inves de 1 dentro da div

Comment: Eu tava fazendo errado, esqueci de fecha a ultima div. agora deu certo.

Comment: @user3192159 com 4: http://jsfiddle.net/qhe7gfd3/1/

Comment: É possivel fazer isso sem usar codigos externos? só com java script dentro do html?   esse aqui não está funcionando  <script>
var buttons = $('#videoGallery button');
var videos = $('#videoGallery div');

buttons.on('click', function () {
    var index = buttons.get().indexOf(this);
    videos.removeClass('yesDisplay');
    videos.eq(index).addClass('yesDisplay');
});
</script>

Comment: @user3192159 sem jQuery? sim, posso juntar isso daqui a pouco se quiseres

Comment: Sim estou tentando evita codigos externos

Comment: @user3192159 sem jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/w8fyzkgc/

Comment: Ficou otimo, essa opção sem a necessidade de codigo externo, vou testa em alguns navegadores pra ver se funciona em todos.